# What does this mean? C++ basic programming

Tags: c++

[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

error on a class private declaration
it was on the int oddnumbers line

```
class odd
{
private:
    int oddnumbers[30], oddsum=0;
    char yes = 'y';
public:
    int oddnum()
    {   
        for(int i; i<30; i++)
            {

                cout<<"Enter odd number #"<<i+1<<": ";
                cin>>oddnumbers[i];
                oddsum=oddsum + oddnumbers[i];
                if(oddnumbers[i]%2 == 0 || oddnumbers == 0 )
                    {   

                        break;
                    }
                cout<<"Do you still want to enter a number(Y/N): ";
                cin>>yes;
                if(yes == 'n'|| yes == 'N')
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        cout<<"Sum is: "<<oddsum<<"\n";
        if(oddnumbers[29] > 0)
        {
        cout<<"\nGoodjob!";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I suggest reading some C++ tutorials carefully to know what is "non-static data member initializers" and debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oddsum` and `yes` are non-static data members (and `oddnumbers` too). The usual place to initialize non-static data members is in the class constructor. So you could rewrite your class like this

```
class odd
{
private:
    int oddnumbers[30], oddsum;
    char yes;
public:
    odd() // constructor
    {
        oddsum = 0;
        yes = 'y';
    }
    int oddnum()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

But a better way would be to realise that all these data members are only used in the method oddnum and therefore you should change them to local variables, like this

```
class odd
{
public:
    int oddnum()
    {   
        int oddnumbers[30], oddsum=0;
        char yes = 'y';
        ...
    }
};
```

But once you have done that you can see that you have a class with no data members and only one method. Such a class doesn't really serve any purpose and you should convert it's method to a global function.

```
int oddnum()
{   
    int oddnumbers[30], oddsum=0;
    char yes = 'y';
    ...
}
```

In this code you are using classes inappropriately. A good C++ book will teach you when to use classes.

Comment: The first part of this answer is very misleading. The "usual" way could be what OP has. If OP were restricted to C++03, *then* it could be argued that the usual way to *initialize* data members is in the constructor initialization list, because what you're showing here is formally not initialization.